# Everytime my mail goes to spam in phpmailer 

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-spam

Here are my codes for sending mail:

```
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $adult = $_POST['adult'];
    $children = $_POST['children'];
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $addition = $_POST['addition'];
    $confirm = $_POST['confirm'];

    $body = '
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Dear Sir,
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Booking request from '.$fullname .'</b><br /><br />
          <u>The details provided are:</u><br />
          <p>Name : '.$fullname.'<br />
          E-mail Address: '.$email.'<br />
          Telephone: '.$telephone.'<br />
          Date: '.$date.'<br />
          Time: '.$time.'<br />
          Adult: '.$adult.'<br />
          Children: '.$children.'<br />
          Company Name: '.$company_name.'<br />
           Confirm by: '.$confirm .'<br />
         Additional Requirements: '.$addition.'<br />
          </p>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <p>Thank you,<br />
        Kaavya Cuisine
        </p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    ';

    $to         = 'sujal@longtail.info';
    $subject    = 'Booking Request';
    $sitename='Website Name';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($to,$sitename);
    $mail->SetFrom($email,$fullname);


    $mail->AddAddress($to, $sitename);
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->Send();
```

Every time I send the mail, it goes in to spam. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: the issue might be in your mail client

Comment: I even tried with my real hotmail address.... $email ='myemail@hotmail.com';

Comment: Please provide some more information ... from where to where do you want to send this email? Have you tried to send a mail using the command-line on that machine?

Comment: The HTML you're using might trigger the spam score. Try sending a plain text-email and report back if it helps.

Comment: ok now i have tried  $to='info@longtail.info'; $email='sujal@longtail.info'; in longtail.info website still spam

Comment: @sujal: What about the plain text email?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on you code i notice that you are sending an email directly from you web page on your domain.

For example you used an @hotmail.com address.

When the recipient receive the emails the mail service of the recipient may test a reverse DNS of the sender of the mail. So the sender is from `@hotmail.com` but the mail comes from your domain which of course is not **hotmail.com**.

So I receive a mail from an address `@hotmail.com` but the IP sender isn't related at all with domain **hotmail.com**: that's SPAM!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

I think a possible solution is: in you PHP code use authenticate with SMTP and from there send the mail!

Comment: Could you possibly show a snippet of you possible solution?

Comment: Also, [here's a bunch of tips from the PHPMailer authors themselves](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters) about how to avoid spam filters.

Answer (score 11):

Normally, an email is marked spam if its "From:" header value's domain part does not match the domain that is actually sending the email.

The easiest way to bypass this is to use a "From:" that matches your domain, and use a "Reply-To:" header to the email that you set in "From:" header

For eg: if you are sending mail from **mydomain.com** and your from email is **me@hotmail.com**, you should change your headers to this:

> From: me@mydomain.com
>
> Reply-To: me@hotmail.com

Comment: i have check with From : info@longtail.info and Reply-To: info@longtail.info still same problem

Answer (score 0):

if this is your full codes then you have to write the path of the PHPMailer thats it.

Ex-

```
require '/...../PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

require '/....../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require '/......./PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';
```

the above will help you.

Answer (score 0):

spam filter of Google or Outlook or whichever you use do this automatically. I believe there is no way make the mail go to inbox programmatically. usually this happens because the sending server is already marked as spam by somebody. The way i found is go to the gmail account mark the item as 'important' in gmail and 'Add to Safe senders' in Outlook.